# Parse custom field data in entry_submission_end_hook

Tags: add-on-development, module, channel, extension

What I'm trying to do is parse the custom field data sent to the `entry_submission_end` hook.

Here's what I was able to dissect out of the channel entries module, but what I'm confused is how to instantiate an instance of `Channel` for use by the template parser library.

```
public function entry_submission_end_hook($entry_id, $entry_metadata, $entry_data) 
{
    $tag_to_parse = "{page_uri}";
    $channel = new Channel; // do I include mod.channel.php and instantiate this, if so how?

    $this->EE->load->library('channel_entries_parser');
    $parser = $this->EE->channel_entries_parser->create($tag_to_parse);
    return $parser->parse($channel, $entry_data);
}
```

Ideally this should return the URI of the page for the entry saved via `entry_submission_end`.

*Alternatively if there is another way to run logic on parsed tag data from a given entry upon saving or creating said entry I'm all ears.*

Comment: Why the costly parse? If it's a specific fieldtype or logic part, can't you just lookup what the method does and replicate? e.g. if it's a specific solution and not a generic add-on, that is. e.g. 2. If you just want the page_uri, then lookup how it is constructed, instead of shooting the template parse howitzer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was able to come up with. I did tap into the channel entries module. This seems excessive since in my scenario it's just taking a single field of text and parsing it but at least it fully implements whatever classes EE has.

I hope this helps someone.

```
public function parse_tagdata($entry_id, $tagdata)
{
    require_once PATH_MOD.'channel/mod.channel.php';

    ee()->TMPL->tagdata = $tagdata;
    ee()->TMPL->tagparams['dynamic'] = "no";
    ee()->TMPL->tagparams['entry_id'] = $entry_id;
    ee()->TMPL->site_ids = array($this->config->item('site_id'));

    $vars = ee()->functions->assign_variables($tagdata);
    ee()->TMPL->var_single  = $vars['var_single'];
    ee()->TMPL->var_pair        = $vars['var_pair'];

    $channel = new Channel;
    $channel->fetch_custom_channel_fields();
    $channel->fetch_custom_member_fields();
    $channel->build_sql_query();
    $channel->query = ee()->db->query($channel->sql);               
    $channel->parse_channel_entries();

    return $channel->return_data;
}
```